# jQuery - disable remaining checkboxes when limit reached

Tags: jquery, counter, checkbox

Relative jQuery newbie:

I want to display a set of checkboxes, of which the user can select five.

I have some jquery code that validates in jsfiddle, but it's not apparently doing anything.

Can anyone see what obvious thing I'm missing?

I have a set of checkboxes, and then the following javascript:

```
function countChecked() {                             
    var n = $("input:checked").length;                       
    alert(n);                          

    if (n == 5) {                                                        
        $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);  
    }                                                        
    else {                                                        
        $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false); 
    }
}    
$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
```

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4ty/)

Comment: Your code is fine your need to choose jQuery framework, http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4ty/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine, you just needed to set the framework to `jQuery` on the left hand side.

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Vg4ty/1/)

Comment: D'oh!  It didn't work in the page I had it in, and I thought my jQuery was wrong- turned out to be a different javascript error.

My bad.  Now I need to remove the alerts and update a text field instead.  Back to the jQuery docs...

Sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: @MarcWilson no problem, I've done it many times myself :) Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted for this question.

Comment: Done- and thanks again.

It's irking me that I didn't spot it- as several people did within a few minutes!

Comment: What possible reason could you have for downvoting this?

Comment: @MarcWilson don't worry, I didn't mean you, just the mystery downvoter who didn't bother to leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

you have Mootools 1.4.5 chosen in your fiddle.. select Jquery 1.8.3 in your dropdown and it will work..

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle is not working because you are setting it using mootolls, not jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4ty/3/

```
JQUERY
```